# Custom typeface text size varies greatly between fonts

Tags: android

I have a few TextViews in my app where I use a custom typeface. I have given the view centered layout gravity to get the text centered in its parent layout. It looks fine in the previewer with the Sans font, but when I change the typeface, the result looks like the text is shifted down, like this:

[image: TextView with Shifted Text]

Compared to this:

[image: TextView with Sans]

Here is the xml for that element:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/Turn_ScoreA_Frame" android:padding="5dp" android:background="@color/teamA_secondary" android:layout_margin="5dp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="110dp">
   <android.view.View android:id="@+id/Turn_ScoreABG" android:background="@color/teamA_primary" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></android.view.View>
   <TextView android:id="@+id/Turn_ScoreA" android:includeFontPadding="false" android:text="5" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="32dp"></TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

This also occurs when I use fill_parent for layout_width and height of the text view, with text gravity center. I set the custom Typeface in the OnCreate of the view in which this layout is used, just by using TextView.SetTypeface.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I'm having trouble tracking anything down on this.

As a note, I've worked around this on several views by setting the margin_bottom to -10dp or so, but I'd like to remove that, and I can't get that hack to work on confined views like this one, anyways.

The font is Anton, by the way.

EDIT: This is definitely the result of the text being too large for its container. The thing is, Sans fits just fine, and the new font *would fit* but its measured size is too large. What I'm hoping is to find a way to get the text to remain at its current visible size and fit in the center of the container, in such a way that doesn't feel too hacky =)

Comment: I think I've at least tracked down the source of this issue. If I put this element inside a much bigger Layout, it centers properly. So I think this is just default behavior for an element whenever it can't fit inside its parent view. It's just that this text thinks its bigger than it actually displays. Still not sure what the best fix is.

Comment: The problem is `android:textSize="32dp"` of textview, cause the TextView's height is not proper to best fit 32dp either make textView height bigger or Text size less.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think those are really the only two good options for a legitimate fix, but now I'm wondering why the text thinks its sized so differently compared to sans. There's just a lot of blank space with that number.

Comment: cause by default size of your custom font is more than the default fonts..And second main thing is always give size to Text in `sp` not `dp` in Android.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using sp. I missed that in the Best Practices section in Google's dev guides.

Comment: Can you postup or link the custom typeface? Would be worthwhile using some font tools to investigate the differences. ttf file?

Comment: The font is a great font, Anton: http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Anton. I've looked at it some myself, but don't know enough about fonts to do much.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Comment: Programmatically add mTextView.setIncludeFontPadding(false) to your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options

[image]

1. Decrease the **`text size`**
2. Increase the height of **`FrameLayout`**
3. Change the **`font`** which can fit correctly
   you cannot change the property of the font, it is designed is such a way that it has empty space above it, which doesn't fit in your given `android:layout_height="50dp"` when  `android:textSize="32dp"`